# Adding JPanel into another JPanel using JButton with addActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jlabel

The commented codes are the problem. When I am using them, panels are added successfully, but I don't need these commented code anymore but same code is not working after I remove or comment those blocks.

Those codes that I have commented need to be removed. Without those commented codes, program runs but does not add panels. I use IntelliJ for my Java Project.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Test extends JFrame{
    JPanel panel;
    JButton send;
    JTextField text;
    JPanel chatArea;
    boolean typing;
    Test(){
        setSize(365,515);
        setLocation(50,100);
        setLayout(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBounds(0,0,350,60);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(90000000));add(panel);

        JLabel name = new JLabel("IRONMAN");
        name.setFont(new Font("SAN_SERIF", Font.PLAIN,14));
        name.setForeground(Color.white);
        name.setBounds(110,35,120,20);panel.add(name);
        text = new JTextField();
        text.setBounds(15,430,260,40);
        text.setFont(new Font("SAN_SERIF",Font.PLAIN,14));
        text.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
//        Timer timer = new Timer(1, event -> {
//            if (!typing){
//                name.setText("IRONMAN");
//            }
//        });
//        timer.setInitialDelay(2000);
//        text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
//            @Override
//            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
//                name.setText("IRONMAN typing...");
//                timer.stop();
//                typing = true;
//            }
//            @Override
//            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
//                typing = false;
//                if (!timer.isRunning()){
//                    timer.start();
//                }
//            }
//        });
        add(text);

        chatArea = new JPanel();
        chatArea.setBounds(5,65,340,350);
        add(chatArea);

        send = new JButton("Send");
        send.setBounds(280,430,65,30);
        send.setBackground(new Color(200,120,255));
        send.setForeground(new Color(7,95,75));
        send.addActionListener(e -> {
            String message = "STARK: "+text.getText();
            JPanel p2 = formatLabel(message);
            chatArea.add(p2);
            text.setText("");
        });
        add(send);
    }
    private JPanel formatLabel(String message) {
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("<html><p style = \"width : 150px\">" + message + "</p></html>");
        label1.setBackground(new Color(200,120,255));
        label1.setForeground(new Color(7,95,75));
        label1.setFont(new Font("SAN_SERIF",Font.PLAIN,18));
        label1.setOpaque(true);
        label1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15,15,15,70));
        p3.add(label1);
        return p3;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain how the program should work to understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First off all some general comments:

```
label1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15,15,15,70));
```

Don't be afraid to use whitespace. For example

```
label1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 70));
```

It is easier for our eyes to see text with whitespace.

```
setLayout(null);
```

Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You can easily use the default BorderLayout of the JFrame. Add:

1. the top panel to BorderLayout.PAGE_START
2. the chat panel to BorderLayout.PAGE_CENTER
3. the bottom panel to BorderLayout.PAGE_END

> after I remove or comment those blocks.

That code is not the solution or the problem.

The problem is that a component has a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

In your existing code try resizing the frame by making it wider. The panel will appear. This is because the resizing will cause the layout manager to be invoked which will give the panel a size so it can be painted.

In your code you need to use:

```
chatArea.add(p2);
chatArea.revalidate();
```

The revalidate() will automatically invoke the layout manager.

Comment: Thankyou. That Solved my problem.

Comment: @varunrao, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.